# select in a parsed json, comparing id with an array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

i need to filter array  result (get by parsed json).

if i know the exact id i can select in the json using

```
@my_art = ele_art.select { |articolo| articolo['id'] == 456 }
```

Now I have an array of ids called @myarray and i need to select in ele_art only the items with id in the array

Reading the array i have:

```
[279, 276]
```

i tried with

```
@my_art = ele_art.select { |articolo| articolo['id'] == @myarray }
```

or

```
@my_art = ele_art.select { |articolo| articolo['id'] in @myarray }
```

with no luck!

how can i solve?

Comment: I see, so, in @myarray you have `[279, 276]` ?, in that case, try with: `@my_art = ele_art.select { |articolo| @myarray.include?(articolo['id']) }`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: great!! this solved my problem! if you convert the comment in answare i can mark the solutionit ! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@my_array` is and array of `id`s, so, in that case you need to check if `articolo['id']` is included in `@myarray`. For those cases, the `Array` class in Ruby has the `include?` method, which receives an `object` and returns true/false if the object is included or not in the array.

So, in your case try something like:

```
@my_art = ele_art.select { |articolo| @myarray.include?(articolo['id']) }
```